# How to aggregating like sets in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I create **sets** of like data and associate back to the linked key.

The example below shows how the raw data and desired output.

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (PID INT, CID INT)

INSERT INTO @Data
VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4),  
       (5, 4), (5, 5), (8, 4), (8, 5), (6, 6), (7, 4), (7, 5), (7, 6)
```

In the data above, CID sets of 1, 2, 3 are different than 1, 2.  These are unique *sets*.

I want to associate

PID 1 and 3 to the set 1, 2, 3.

PID 2 to set 1, 2

PID 4 to set 3, 4

PID 5 and 8 to set 4, 5

etc.

The overall goal is to return XML which looks similar to:

```
<Items>
  <Item>
    <Hierarchies>
        <Hierarchy>
           <CID>1</CID>
           <CID>2</CID>
           <CID>3</CID>
        </Hierarchy>
    </Hierarchies>
    <PIDs>
        <PID>1</PID>
        <PID>3</PID>
    </PIDs>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Hierarchies>
        <Hierarchy>
           <CID>1</CID>
           <CID>2</CID>
        </Hierarchy>
    </Hierarchies>
    <PIDs>
        <PID>2</PID>
    </PIDs>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Hierarchies>
        <Hierarchy>
           <CID>3</CID>
           <CID>4</CID>
        </Hierarchy>
    </Hierarchies>
    <PIDs>
        <PID>4</PID>
    </PIDs>
  </Item>
  <Item>
      ... Etc ...
  </Item>
<Items>
```

Comment: At this point... caffeine.  Tried using PIVOT (which I dont understand much about) and creating crazy cursor based logic.  Right now, I'm just lost.  I'm OK with creating the XML, the aggregation is where I am getting stuck.

Comment: Have you tried putting down the keyboard, pulling out a pencil and paper, and trying to describe a step-by-step algorithm that takes you from input to output?

Comment: Can you explain in simple English what you are trying to accomplish?  If you can't, you won't ever get there.

Comment: Have you tried `FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('blah')`? It's in SQL Server BOL ... though I suppose this is only part of the solution really.

Comment: :) Yes, I've written it down multiple times.  After speaking with a colleague here, I believe I am asking the wrong question.  Not necessarily aggregation (i.e. COUNT, MAX, etc) but more of grouping by Sets.  I need to know which PID falls within Set 1, 2, 3, which PIDs fall in Set 1, 2 (which is different than 1, 2, 3), which PIDs in 4, 5, etc...

Comment: Updated question for more clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this? or I did misunderstood?

```
    DECLARE @Data TABLE (PID INT, CID INT)

    INSERT INTO @Data
    VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4),  
           (5, 4), (5, 5), (8, 4), (8, 5), (6, 6), (7, 4), (7, 5), (7, 6)

    with cid_xml as (   select P.PID
                               ,OA.CID
                        from @Data P
                        outer apply (select CAST((select C.CID 
                                                     from @Data C
                                                  where C.PID = P.PID

                                                  for xml path('')) as varchar(max)) as CID 
                                    ) OA
                    )
    select cast((select cast(C2.CID as xml) as 'hierarchies/hierarchy'
                        ,cast(OA2.PID as xml) as 'PIDs'
                from cid_xml C2
                outer apply (select CAST((select C3.PID 
                                             from cid_xml C3
                                          where C3.CID = C2.CID
                                          group by C3.PID
                                          for xml path('')) as varchar(max)) as PID 
                            )OA2
                group by C2.CID,OA2.PID
                order by LEN(C2.CID) desc
                for xml path('item')) as xml)
    for xml path('Items')
```

I just did the order by to see the first nodes of item/hierarchies/hierarchy as you did in your sample of aim result

the resultset that I got was

```
  <Items>
    <item>
      <hierarchies>
        <hierarchy>
          <CID>1</CID>
          <CID>2</CID>
          <CID>3</CID>
        </hierarchy>
      </hierarchies>
      <PIDs>
        <PID>1</PID>
        <PID>3</PID>
      </PIDs>
    </item>
    <item>
      <hierarchies>
        <hierarchy>
          <CID>4</CID>
          <CID>5</CID>
          <CID>6</CID>
        </hierarchy>
      </hierarchies>
      <PIDs>
        <PID>7</PID>
      </PIDs>
    </item>
    <item>
      <hierarchies>
        <hierarchy>
          <CID>3</CID>
          <CID>4</CID>
        </hierarchy>
      </hierarchies>
      <PIDs>
        <PID>4</PID>
      </PIDs>
    </item>
    <item>
      <hierarchies>
        <hierarchy>
          <CID>4</CID>
          <CID>5</CID>
        </hierarchy>
      </hierarchies>
      <PIDs>
        <PID>5</PID>
        <PID>8</PID>
      </PIDs>
    </item>
    <item>
      <hierarchies>
        <hierarchy>
          <CID>1</CID>
          <CID>2</CID>
        </hierarchy>
      </hierarchies>
      <PIDs>
        <PID>2</PID>
      </PIDs>
    </item>
    <item>
      <hierarchies>
        <hierarchy>
          <CID>6</CID>
        </hierarchy>
      </hierarchies>
      <PIDs>
        <PID>6</PID>
      </PIDs>
    </item>
  </Items>
```

it's ok?

Comment: Looks like that did the trick! Thanks for educating me and your help!  Going to apply this to my solution to double make sure it fits.